# cannot implicitly convert type 'System.EventHandler' to 'System.EventHandler<object>'

Tags: c#, windows-8

I am trying to fade a text box within specified time. This code works on Windows Phone but it doesn't work in a Windows 8 application. I made changes to fix as many errors as possible. but I couldn't resolve one of them: `cannot implicitly convert type 'System.EventHandler' to 'System.EventHandler<object>"` arises on the expression `sb.Completed += ehl`. The full function is below:

```
    public static void Fade(UIElement target, double ValueFrom, double ValueTo, double Duration)
    {
        DoubleAnimation da = new DoubleAnimation();
        da.From = ValueFrom;
        da.To = ValueTo;
        da.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Duration);
        da.AutoReverse = false;

        Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(da, "opacity");

        Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.Storyboard.SetTarget(da, target);

        Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.Storyboard sb = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.Storyboard();
        sb.Children.Add(da);

        EventHandler ehl = null;
        ehl = (s, args) =>
        {

            sb.Stop();
            sb.Completed+= ehl; //error occurs here
            target.Opacity = ValueTo;
        };
        sb.Completed += ehl; //error occurs here

        sb.Begin();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The type of the [`Completed` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.timeline.completed) is `EventHandler<object>`, but you declare your event handler is of type `EventHandler`, and not `EventHandler<object>`.

That's exactly what the error message tells you, so you should change the type of your event handler to  `EventHandler<object>`.

BTW, the line `sb.Completed+= ehl;` *inside* the event handler seems strange to be. You are basically attaching the handler to the event *again* every time the event handler is called.

Comment: But the above method works fine in windows phone.Its not working only in windows 8 application.I even tried EventHadler<object> but its not working. Do you know the exact corrections?

Comment: @HariVignesh - the original code above **compiles** if I change `EventHandler` to `EventHandler<object>`. Maybe you mean something else when you say "its not working," but you will have to be more specific.